# Какая система инициализации используется в данный момент?

Tags: linux

Насколько я понял upstart, программа, запускающая все остальные программы в системе, использует скрипты в `/etc/init`. В то время как её аналог systemd использует для запуска программ скрипты из `/etc/init.d`.

Но у меня есть две этих папки `/etc/init` и `/etc/init.d`. В каждой из них есть скрипт запуска nginx. Они отличаются содержимым. Так вряд ли было бы, будь у них одинаковый функционал.

Как определить, какая служба используется для управления процессами: Upstart, systemd, стандартный init?

Comment: А что за Linux у Вас?

Comment: init.d - это вообще для старого sysvinit и используется для обратной совместимости и в upstart, и в systemd

Comment: @MishaPolitaev просто init, что то очень нестандартное. Видел где то такой каталог, но к загрузке системы он отношения не имел. Так что init.d лучше смотрите. И еще в rc.d (rc.3 и т.п.), если они есть лежат ссылки на все, что запускается.

Comment: посмотрите вот это вопрос, он должен вам помочь
[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sysvinit и [прочие пришедшие ему на замену системы инициализации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#Replacements_for_init)  unix-подобных операционных систем могут присутствовать в отдельно взятой установке **одновременно**.

какой первый процесс запустит программа, выполняющая функции ядра операционной системы, после собственной загрузки и инициализации, «того и тапки».

если эти функции исполняет программа *linux*, то по умолчанию она запускает программу/скрипт, находящийся в файле `/sbin/init`. данное поведение можно переопределить, передав параметр загрузки `init=/путь/к/файлу`. узнать, передан ли такой параметр, несложно:

```
$ grep -o 'init=\w*' /proc/cmdline
```

---

лишь по одному «внешнему виду» файла `/sbin/init` определить, какой именно из систем инициализации он принадлежит, затруднительно. разве что он является символической ссылкой на файл с более «выразительным» именем. например:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/init 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Aug 29 18:45 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

но если в данной установке используется пакетный менеджер, то, скорее всего, этот файл принадлежит какому-нибудь пакету. примеры запросов к пакетным менеджерам:

```
$ dpkg -S /sbin/init 
$ rpm -qf /sbin/init
$ equery belongs /sbin/init
$ pacman -Qo /sbin/init
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы определить, какая система инициализации в `linux` системе используется, `upstart` или `systemd`(как самые популярные на текущий момент) я написал такой скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -o nounset
#set -o errexit     

UNKNOW_EXITCODE=4
SYSTEMD_EXITCODE=5
UPSTART_EXITCODE=6

test -d /run/systemd/system; systemd=$?
if [ $systemd == 0 ]
then
    exit $SYSTEMD_EXITCODE;
fi;

command -v initctl >/dev/null 2>&1 && { initctl --version | grep -q upstart;}
upstart=$?
if [ $upstart == 0 ]
then
    exit $UPSTART_EXITCODE;
fi;

exit $UNKNOW_EXITCODE;
```

Исхожу из предположения, что на системе установлена одна init-система.